# Miscalculation after subsetting in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, match, subset

I have an issue in calculating correctly upon subsetting the data. However initially I extract some information from file to another. Then, I try to calculate the number of patients per organ. The commands that were working before properly now gives me an error. It doesn't show any error -just miscalculating the values.

Input files are in this link:https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8bo4b4dpmydj19w/AADZ7WuoecrjPwm_qyF8NRMza?dl=0

Here is my command lines.

```
Clinical_Samples_map = read.xls("b.xlsx") # calling my file
Clinical_Samples_Original = read.xls("a.xlsx", sheet=1) # the file where I get additional information

Clinical_Samples_map$AnatomicLocation = Clinical_Samples_Original[match(Clinical_Samples_map$SampleID, Clinical_Samples_Original$TubeName),"AnatomicLocation"] 

map<-Clinical_Samples_map # Just changing the name

# Anatomic Location

sub_map_AnatomicLocation <- map[!duplicated(map$patient_number), ] # Excluding the duplicate of patient by checking patient_number column
sub_map_AnatomicLocation <- data.frame(sub_map_AnatomicLocation) 
sub_map_AnatomicLocation_patient <- subset(sub_map_AnatomicLocation, Disease != "Unknown" & AnatomicLocation != "Unknown") # Getting rid of "Unknown" value if there is any


AnatomicLocation_patient <- count_(sub_map_AnatomicLocation , c("Disease","AnatomicLocation"))

write.table(AnatomicLocation_patient, "AnatomicLocation_patient.txt",col.names = TRUE)
write.table(Clinical_Samples_map, "Clinical_Samples_map2.txt",col.names = TRUE)
```

However, when I compare two written txt file I have different numbers. Does anyone know why this happens? For instance, if you have a look at CD Ileum number it shows 3 patients however when I look Clinical_Samples_map2.txt I can count 4.

Additional things, if I try to generate some plots with ggplot:

```
ggplot(data=Clinical_Samples_map, aes(x=Disease, y=AgeAtSampling, fill=Disease)) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE) +  
  ggtitle("Clinical_Samples_map_Disease") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Age at Sampling", breaks = seq(0, 80, 20), limits=c(0, 80)) +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Disease") + 
  geom_jitter(colour = "black", size = 2, width = 0.15, height = 0.3) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(fill = "Disease") + 
  theme(axis.title=element_text(face="plain", size="30", color="black",family = "Gill Sans MT"), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=20,angle=45,hjust=.5,vjust=.5,face="plain"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(colour="grey20",size=20,angle=0,hjust=1,vjust=0,face="plain"), 
        legend.text=element_text(face="plain", size="30", color="black"),
        legend.title=element_text(face="plain", size="30", color="black"))
```

I got an error:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

I think that is the problem. I can overcome this to generate plot but I can not figure out why it calculates wrong?

Can anybody help with this issue? I am struggling for so long and couldn't figure it out yet.

Thank you very much.

Bahti

Comment: Sorry my mistake... Here are the library that used: library(gdata) and library(dplyr)...

Comment: Please update your post with the `library` lines and not in comments, so all can see.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. Since I never had this problem I never thought about it. I just needed to change into characters some columns

```
map[] <- lapply(map, as.character)
```

I used this first and the for specific columns I used

map_AnatomicLocation$AgeAtSampling=as.numeric(levels(map_AnatomicLocation$AgeAtSampling))[map_AnatomicLocation$AgeAtSampling] # If there is a problem with discret values

Then it allowed me to plot and calculate.

Comment: What does this solution resolve? Your miscalculation or `ggplot` error? While you are encouraged to answer your own question, please answer fully and generally for future readers (almost like talking to *past* self).